# get current logged user name & its ID in sharepoint 2010 using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am not getting the current user name and id by this method why is anything wrong in it.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserInfo",
    async: false,
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
            curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
            curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
            curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID")+";#"+$(this).attr("Name");
        });
    }
});
alert(curUserId);
```

Comment: What are you getting ? Error or blank data ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = null;  
var web = null;  
var currentUser = null;  
function getWebUserData() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    currentUser.retrieve();
    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    alert('User name:' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName());
}
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```